# cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab is not working but cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY is working

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to run this code, and it will give error:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('image1.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
hsl = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
cv2.imshow('image',hsl)
cv2.imwrite('hsl.jpg',hsl)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ques3.py", line 7, in <module>
hsl = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2Lab'
```

If I change `cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab` to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, it run succesfully.

Why does this happen?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error (as the last line of the exception thrown indicates) is that the *CV2* (*Python*) module doesn't export a constant named ***COLOR_BGR2Lab***, although [[OpenCV.Docs]: Color conversions - RGB <-> CIE L*a*b*](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_lab)  states that it should. 
According to some *URL* that no longer exists, in a previous (ancient) version the constant was named ***COLOR_BGR2LAB*** (*Python* is case sensitive).

In any case, if you want to see the names that a module exports (in this case for *CV2*) you might use:

```py
import cv2
print(dir(cv2))
```

Comment: but there is also cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab in http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0a860b72b4741c431e81340fafef5eca24&gsc.tab=0    what is this small Lab

Comment: I see. Looking at http://www.pythonbackend.com/topic/1361940473 seems that in `cv2` the constant names have changed from `cv`. Anyway, only a name present in the list returned by the `dir` function (as I posted the code) can be successfully used as e.g.: `cv2`._somename_. Also, the doc you mentioned applies to _C_. The _python_ module might be different. BTW: the `cv2` module is written in python or it's dynamic? You can check that by looking at the file extension from: `print(cv2)` (after importing `cv2`).